# How do you use the blur function in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, blur

I'm trying to blur a section of my code for a website. This is the code and image for what i'm trying to do

This is the CSS

```
    #blur {
box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.80)
    }
```

This is the code

```
     <div>
    <img class="logo" src="logo.jpg" alt="Kusko logo">
    <h1 class="lobsterfont">Kusko Enterprise</h1>
    <h3 class="lobsterfont">Home, Baby and More!</h3>
    <h3 class="aboutbar quicksandfont">Home &nbsp;| &nbsp; About &nbsp;|&nbsp; Contact Us</h3>
</div>
```

And this is what I get. It's not able to show the blurred feature below the section, but somewhere above the h1 element:

[image]

When I try to test and see the problem, by removing the logo and the 'Home | About | Contact Us', It works perfectly:

```
     <div>
    <h1 class="lobsterfont">Kusko Enterprise</h1>
    <h3 class="lobsterfont">Home, Baby and More!</h3>
</div>
```

[image]

So what then am I doing wrong with the code?
I'd apreciate any opinion

Comment: please provide the code as a snippet not as a picture. If you want to have help, you should type it yourself and not expect others to type it down for you. Also provide the CSS. you dont get a blur effect by simply addign id="blur". Last but not least, whats not goign as expected? simply saying that is my code and it doesnt work as expected isnt very helpful.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I added the css and didn't add it to the question. next time i'd use the snippet instead

Comment: `box-shadow` isn't blur

Answer (score 2):

If you want the image or section to be blurred, you need to add though `CSS`, adding id name with blur in `html` won't do anything.

```css
#blur-image, #blur-text {
  filter: blur(8px); // blur effect
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642702909-dec73df255d7?ixlib=rb- 
   1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80" id="blur-image">
<div id="blur-text">
  <h3>Testing testing </h3>
  <h4>Testing testing </h4>
</div>
```

Comment: That is what I did, or is this wrong:  #blur {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.80)
}

Comment: `#blur { box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.80) }` won't give you blur effect but instead `box-shadow` around your section, use `filter: blur(8px);` if you want blur effect.

Comment: Your code helped me blur the section itself, but I wanted to get the box-shadow effect around the whole section. I apologize for not sending the code itself

Comment: in that case you should edit qour question and also state that you want to use box-shadow effect not a blur effect.